# Can I programatically invite external users to Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Explanation on the Scenario:
We are building a multi tenanted SAAS application to be hosted in Azure and are planning to use AAD for authenticating tenant users.

Once a customer (tenant) purchases license, we want to pro-grammatically invite the first user to access the products web application.

Beyond that point, we plan to add functionality in the product's web application to enable the admin user to invite other users from his organization to access the web application.

i.e. we plan to use AAD as the identify mgt/authentication provider for our product hosted in Azure. Any feedback on this approach will be much appreciated.

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your scenario, I think it should be better to use code and call api to achieve your goal.  You can use Microsoft Graph and use [the invitation API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/invitation_post) to create a new invitation. Invitation adds an external user to the organization.

[Here is a code sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-code-samples#code-sample) for calling the invitation API to invite users, in "app-only" mode, to get the redemption URL for the resource to which you are inviting the B2B user. The goal is to send a custom invitation email. The email can be composed with an HTTP client, so you can customize how it looks and send it through Graph API.

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace SampleInviteApp {
    class Program {
        /// <summary>
        /// Microsoft graph resource.
        /// </summary>
        static readonly string GraphResource = "https://graph.microsoft.com";

        /// <summary>
        /// Microsoft graph invite endpoint.
        /// </summary>
        static readonly string InviteEndPoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations";

        /// <summary>
        ///  Authentication endpoint to get token.
        /// </summary>
        static readonly string EstsLoginEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com";

        /// <summary>
        /// This is the tenantid of the tenant you want to invite users to.
        /// </summary>
        private static readonly string TenantID = "";

        /// <summary>
        /// This is the application id of the application that is registered in the above tenant.
        /// The required scopes are available in the below link.
        /// https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/invitation_post
        /// </summary>
        private static readonly string TestAppClientId = "";

        /// <summary>
        /// Client secret of the application.
        /// </summary>
        private static readonly string TestAppClientSecret = "@";

        /// <summary>
        /// This is the email address of the user you want to invite.
        /// </summary>
        private static readonly string InvitedUserEmailAddress = @"";

        /// <summary>
        /// This is the display name of the user you want to invite.
        /// </summary>
        private static readonly string InvitedUserDisplayName = @"";

        /// <summary>
        /// Main method.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">Optional arguments</param>
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Invitation invitation = CreateInvitation();
            SendInvitation(invitation);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create the invitation object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns the invitation object.</returns>
        private static Invitation CreateInvitation() {
            // Set the invitation object.
            Invitation invitation = new Invitation();
            invitation.InvitedUserDisplayName = InvitedUserDisplayName;
            invitation.InvitedUserEmailAddress = InvitedUserEmailAddress;
            invitation.InviteRedirectUrl = "https://www.microsoft.com";
            invitation.SendInvitationMessage = true;

            return invitation;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Send the guest user invite request.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="invitation">Invitation object.</param>
        private static void SendInvitation(Invitation invitation) {
            string accessToken = GetAccessToken();

            HttpClient httpClient = GetHttpClient(accessToken);

            // Make the invite call. 
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(invitation));
            content.Headers.Add("ContentType", "application/json");

            var postResponse = httpClient.PostAsync(InviteEndPoint, content).Result;
            string serverResponse = postResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Console.WriteLine(serverResponse);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the HTTP client.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="accessToken">Access token</param>
        /// <returns>Returns the Http Client.</returns>
        private static HttpClient GetHttpClient(string accessToken) {
            // setup http client.
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("client-request-id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

            Console.WriteLine(
                "CorrelationID for the request: {0}",
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.GetValues("client-request-id").Single());

            return httpClient;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the access token for our application to talk to microsoft graph.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns the access token for our application to talk to microsoft graph.</returns>
        private static string GetAccessToken() {
            string accessToken = null;

            // Get the access token for our application to talk to microsoft graph.
            try {
                AuthenticationContext testAuthContext =
                    new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("{0}/{1}", EstsLoginEndpoint, TenantID));
                AuthenticationResult testAuthResult = testAuthContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
                    GraphResource,
                    new ClientCredential(TestAppClientId, TestAppClientSecret)).Result;
                accessToken = testAuthResult.AccessToken;

            } catch (AdalException ex) {
                Console.WriteLine("An exception was thrown while fetching the token: {0}.", ex);
                throw;
            }

            return accessToken;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invitation class.
        /// </summary>
        public class Invitation {
            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets display name.
            /// </summary>
            public string InvitedUserDisplayName { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets display name.
            /// </summary>
            public string InvitedUserEmailAddress { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether Invitation Manager should send the email to InvitedUser.
            /// </summary>
            public bool SendInvitationMessage { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets invitation redirect URL
            /// </summary>
            public string InviteRedirectUrl { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!